# Node with mongo: findByIdAndUpdate not updating document

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am trying to update doc in mongo with node. I am doing that:

```
var id = data[0]._id;

            var updated = {
                level: mod.level,
                levelName: mod.levelName,
                levelType: mod.levelType,
                map: mod.map,
                waves: mod.waves
            };

            model.findByIdAndUpdate(id, updated, function(err, data){
                if(err){
                    console.log('error');
                    console.log(err);
                    res.send(err);
                } else {
                    console.log('update');
                    console.log(data);
                    res.send({ data: 'Record has been updated' });
                }
            });
```

The process is going to else clause, i can see 'update' log, then there is a null in next console.log and the change is not reflected in db. Is there any obvious error here? I've read documentations and it seems to be valid but somehow it just don't want to work.

This is my schema:

```
var Schema = mongo.Schema;

var LevelSchema = new Schema({
    level: { type: String },
    levelName: { type: String },
    levelType: { type: String },
    map: { type: Object },
    waves: { type: Object }
}, { versionKey: false });
```

Comment: Try running `model.findById(id)` and logging the result, just to make sure the filter actually matched something.

Comment: You were right, it seems that I had to add _id in schema, after I added it it appears in findById and it started to update docs.

Comment: But in fact I don't want to have it in schema, because it is not working when I am saving new document (I don't have _id in new document - it is generated)

Comment: You might try with strictQuery to see if that affects it.

Comment: Hmm, the same with srtictQuery, update not working findById cannot find document

Comment: try cranking up the logging verbosity on the database to see the query, so you can determine what exactly mongoose is sending when the update doesn't work.

Comment: Hmm I am not so familiar with mongo, may you tell me how to do that?

Comment: depends on how you are running it: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.setLogLevel/#db.setloglevel--

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251442/discussion-between-sennin-and-joe).

Answer (score 0):

Update your code with this to resolve the error :

```
model.findByIdAndUpdate(id, updated, { new: true }, function(err, updatedData) {
    if(err){
                    console.log('error');
                    console.log(err);
                    res.send(err);
                } else {
                    console.log('update');
                    console.log(data);
                    res.send({ data: 'Record has been updated' });
                }
});
```